# Why is borrowing a &mut reference from an immutable array sometimes possible?

Tags: rust

Let's try to compile this code:

```
trait Bar {
    fn bar(&mut self);
}

fn foo(a1: &mut Bar, j: usize) {
    let a = [a1];
    a[0].bar(); //compilation ok
    a[j % 2].bar();
}

fn main() {}
```

Compilation error:

```
error[E0596]: cannot borrow immutable local variable `a` as mutable
 --> src/main.rs:8:5
  |
6 |     let a = [a1];
  |         - consider changing this to `mut a`
7 |     a[0].bar(); //compilation ok
8 |     a[j % 2].bar();
  |     ^ cannot borrow mutably
```

Why is `a[0].bar()` OK, but `a[j % 2].bar()` fails? Is it a compiler bug?

Comment: I don't know why this specific example behaves the way it does, but I do know that there are cases where the compiler allows a non-`mut` binding to be mutably borrowed *if* the compiler knows that the binding is never used anywhere else (*i.e.* as though you were moving, not borrowing).  It could be related to that.  Possibly also has something to do with the compiler being able to better reason about indexing on a constant index, rather than a dynamic one.

Comment: Strangely, `a[0+0].bar();` doesn't compile, but `a[j].bar();` does compile. So this doesn't seem related to whether the index is a constant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it a compiler bug?

[Yes](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/46095). It is fixed in Rust 1.25.0-nightly (2018-01-09 61452e506f0c88861cccaeea4ced3419bdb3cbe0) by [PR 47167](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/47167)

The short version is that there are two ways of performing indexing, referred to as "builtin indexing" and "overloaded indexing". As you might be able to guess from the names, one is more intrinsic to the compiler and the other is more user-customizable.

In this case, the overloaded indexing is performing an unneeded borrow of the array, triggering the warning. You can work around the problem by simplifying the compilers job of type inference:

```
fn foo(a1: &mut Bar, j: usize) {
    let a = [a1];
    let x: usize = j % 2;
    a[x].bar();
}
```

By explicitly stating the index is a `usize`, the code will now use the builtin indexing.